# Edit is missing and Add Item not working in 2sxc 9.32.1 on DNN EVOQ BASIC v. 09.01.01

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke-9, dnn9

Just upgraded to DNN EVOQ BASIC v. 09.01.01 (113) and 2sxc 9.32.1

After placing the Content module on a page, some of our templates do not have Edit options and some of them that have an Add Item option doesn't do anything after clicked.

When I click on Add Item, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.t.showDetailedHttpError (ToSic.Sxc.Instance.ts:73)
    at fire (jquery.js?cdv=209:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js?cdv=209:1148)
    at done (jquery.js?cdv=209:8076)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js?cdv=209:8598)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a skin / container compatibility issue, the "content module" you mention,  is this the core text / html module or something else?

As a test, change the page skin and or module container to one that comes with the core 9.1.1 install and retest

DC

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure what's happening, but let me give you a bit of background. When an editor is on the page, 2sxc adds some configuration information as json in the html-attributes, which the UI the needs to know what you were clicking on etc.

To me it sound like something is breaking this - either because a server-side filter is changing the HTML (not likely, but possible), or another javascript is running which changes the DOM, resulting in removed or broken attributes.

To get this resolved, pls verify that you can find these jsons in the html-tags (they are very obvious) by looking at the html-source. If they are there and look ok, it's not the server that's breaking it.

Then check if they are still there in Chrome-Debugger (F12) which doesn't show you the source as the server sent it, but the source as the browser currently has it. I'm pretty sure it will be off somehow, because maybe a neat jQuery mangles the HTML.

Love from Switzerland,
iJungleboy